# How can I generate a KES Signature using cardano-serialization-lib?

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-serialization-lib, signing-key-file

Cardano Serialization Lib has this class:

```
export class KESSignature {
  free(): void;
/**
* @returns {Uint8Array}
*/
  to_bytes(): Uint8Array;
/**
* @param {Uint8Array} bytes
* @returns {KESSignature}
*/
  static from_bytes(bytes: Uint8Array): KESSignature;
}
```

What `Uint8Array` should I provide to the `from_bytes` method to obtain a valid `KESSignature`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [`cardanocli-js`](https://github.com/shareslake/cardanocli-js) to generate the KES signature file.

You can do it like this:

```
const CardanocliJs = require("cardanocli-js");

const shelleyGenesisPath = "/path/to/your/testnet-shelley-genesis.json";
const options = {
  shelleyGenesisPath,
  network: "testnet-magic 1097911063"
};

const cardanocliJs = new CardanocliJs(options);

const nodeKeyGenKES = cardanocliJs.nodeKeyGenKES(stakePoolName);
```